Flink 1.16 with Gauge/Histogram Custom metrics with custom labels/variables
Requirement - Want to implement Gauge/Histogram Custom metrics with user defied variables/Labels to the flink application.The values for the custom labels will only know at runtime.
Flink version - 1.16

As per the documentation we can use addGroup method to define user defile variable
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/ops/metrics/#user-variables
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/ops/metrics/#user-scope
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/ops/metrics/#gauge

getRuntimeContext()
  .getMetricGroup()
  .addGroup("MYLable", "Value")


I have used the below implementation and trying to create thi.metricGroup.addGroup("test1", value) with dynamic values.

public class MyMapper extends RichMapFunction<String, String> {
  private transient String valueToExpose;
   private MetricGroup metricGroup;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration config) {
   this.metricGroup = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup();

    this.metricGroup.gauge("MyGauge", new Gauge<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue() {
          return valueToExpose;
        }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public String map(String value) throws Exception {
    
    thi.metricGroup.addGroup("test1", value)

    return value;
  }
}


Metrics created with "MyGauge" but fields not visible into the metrics.

Can you please help me why labels are not visible to custom metrics?
is there any configuration missing for the custom labels?
Can you share some sample for the Flink metrics with custom labels.

I've never tried to add a new metric while the workflow was running - I think it might only work in the open() method of the function. I have run a workflow to first collect the set of possible values, and then passed that to the constructor of a second worfkflow's function...but this only makes sense when using Flink to do batch processing.
